# Mariadb 10 Mysql Workbench Maintenace Not Supported

Tags: mysql-workbench, mariadb

Maintenace tasks such as servers status, client connections etc call come up with the same error.

The version of the server you're trying to connect to is 10.0, which is not supported by Workbench.

Is there a quick hack to allow the use of these with Mariadb 10.04 or 10.06

Comment: did you manage to find a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL Workbench checks for the specific version of the server since each version supports a different set of configuration options. E.g. some 5.6 options must not be set on a 5.5 server.

MariaDB is not officially supported. It could be possible to hack the version check to make it pass with 10.0, but much with the differences between the fork and the original MySQL versions there is a chance that you could run into errors or break your server's configuration. The settings in MariaDB are not 100% compatible.

For that reason it is recommended to use a different tool that has dedicated support for MariaDB.